# How to get all dates of week into an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am trying to get all dates into an array in `JavaScript`. I am given only start date and end date of week. Now I want all dates in array that lies in that range of week. For example my week range is -  Oct 26, 2014 - Nov 1, 2014. Now I want [26 ,27 ,28 ,29 ,30 ,31 , 1] which includes all dates of week.

Comment: I dont have. I didn't find any help. I have only first date and last date of week.

Comment: @ShivekParmar Now use your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 10, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0);
const DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    alert(date);
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + DAY);
}
```

Comment: I just give you some hint and example. What you mean does not output good?

Comment: my mistake. I was checking for November. But I had to check for october. your code rocks.